# How to prove a goal from contradictory hypotheses?

Tags: coq

I have hypotheses `i <= 0` and `i >= 2` in my context. How can I prove my goal? are there  tactics for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve this automatically with [Omega](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/omega.html) tactic.

```
Require Import Omega.
Open Scope Z_scope.

Lemma xxx : forall i : Z, i <= 0 -> i >= 2 -> False.
  Proof.
    intros.
    omega.
  Qed.
```

Comment: Has max said, ``omega`` is a powerful tool to get rid of such goals. If you are more interested in "why is this false", you can build a contradiction by hand using the fact that you can infer from your hypotheses that ``2 <= 0 `` (using ``le_trans``) and then the fact that ``n <= 0 -> n = 0`` (``le_n_O``) and then ``discriminate``.

Comment: @Vinz, can you please elaborate? Maybe post another answer? I will gladly upvote it.

Comment: Sure, here you go. Btw there is no ``le_n_O`` but using ``le_refl`` and ``le_Sn_O`` you can easily prove it for natural numbers.

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested in the content of a proof, rather than just "is it true or false", here is a script "by hand" which details one way to prove this proposition. By the way, since the OP didn't give the type of `i`, I first assume it is a natural number.

```
Lemma xxx : forall i : nat, i <= 0 -> i >= 2 -> False.
Proof.
intros i h_i_O h_2_i.
assert (h_2_O: 2 <= 0).
- apply le_trans with i.
  + exact h_2_i. (* i >= 2 is just a notation for 2 <= i *)
  + exact h_i_O.
- apply le_Sn_O in h_2_O.
  contradiction.
Qed.
```

The idea is to say: if `2 <= i <= 0` then `2 <= 0` and it is impossible that any number of the shape `S n` is less or equal than `0`.

If you need the same result on `Z`:

```
Lemma yyy : forall i : Z, i <= 0 -> i >= 2 -> False.
Proof.
intros i h_i_O h_2_i.
assert (h_2_O: 2 <= 0).
- apply Zle_trans with i.
  + apply Z.ge_le; exact h_2_i. (* here we first need to switch the direction of <= by hand *)
  + exact h_i_O.
- vm_compute in h_2_O. 
  apply h_2_O; reflexivity.
Qed.
```

The main difference is how both `<=` operators `le` and `Z.le` are defined. `Z.le` is build on top of a decidable function `Z.compare (a.k.a. ?=)` (basically, `Z.le a b` means `Z.compare a b <> Gt`) so the `vm_compute` invocation asks `Z.compare` to compute the result of `2 ?= 0`, which is `Gt` (2 is greater than 0), so you end up having the hypothesis `Gt = Gt -> False` which is used to close the goal.

There are other ways to prove it, you should have a look at the libraries about `nat` and `Z`. You can also compare these script with the one generated by `Omega` by printing (`Print xxx`) the content of the proof after the Qed.

Best,

V.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried to print and explore omega-generated proof but it is quite incomprehensible and refers to some internals like `fast_OMEGA13`.

Comment: Iirc it is not an internal but a intermediate step. Try to ``Print fast_OMEGA13`` to see if you can check it. Have a look at http://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual023.html to see how it works (quite a big hammer for this particular proof :p)